# In Dafny, how can a method of one object modify another object?

Tags: dafny

This Dafny code fails to compile:

```
class Inner {
  method m1() modifies this {}
}

class Outer {
  var inner: Inner
  constructor(rvec: Inner) { inner := rvec; }

  method m2()
    modifies this, this.inner
  {
    var i := 0;
    while i < 3
    {
      inner.m1();
      i := i + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
Dafny 2.1.1.10209
stdin.dfy(15,18): Error: call may violate context's modifies clause
Dafny program verifier finished with 1 verified, 1 error
```

What's going on here? If I remove the loop, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`method m2() modifies this.inner`, or equivalently `modifies inner`, apparently refers to the value of `this.inner` *on entry* to `m2`. That is, `old(this.inner)` is the specific object that `m2` is allowed to modify.

You'll get this error if Dafny loses the thread and can't be sure that `inner` has not changed.

To fix it:

- The easiest fix is to change `modifies this, this.inner` to just `modifies this.inner`. That way, Dafny knows that nothing in the method can assign to the fields of `this`. So `inner` must refer to the same object throughout.
- But in real code, maybe you also need to modify some fields of `this`. In that case, you can prove that `this.inner` hasn't changed the same way you would prove anything else; if you've got a `while` loop, use an invariant:

  ```
  while i < 3
    invariant inner == old(inner)
  {
    ...
  }
  ```